# Cordova/iOS - Link styling doesn't work - how do i have to change my code

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, styles

i have a problem. I want my linked images to get styled when clicking on it in iOS. I have my links like this ->

```
<li>
    <a href="#news" data-transition="slide">
       <img src="img/start/btnnews.png" width="320px" height="40px" class="link"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

and then my styles like ->

```
a:link{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  #000000;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

a:visited{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  #000000;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

a:hover{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: #000000;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

a:focus{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  #000000;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

a:active{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  #000000;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

i added them all, because i wanted to test if this is working or not. For me: It is not, but i dont know why. My images don't change anything.

(My Navigation is floated left, when this is relevant)

So i read a lot about link styling on ios but...is there no easy way to overlay my images by a light grey, when clicking on one of them?

Just found out ->

```
.link:active{
-webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
```

works with my images. But the coloring doesn't work.

So...time is going...and i tryed to add a opacity to my links (THIS WORKS) ->

```
 <script language="javascript">
function hide_selection(){
    var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
    for(i=0; i<lnks.length; i++){
        if (lnks[i].className == "selected_link"){
            lnks[i].className = "";
            break;
        }
    }
}

function selectLink(ob){
    hide_selection();
    ob.className = "selected_link";
}
</script>
```

and my link ->

```
  <li>
      <a href="#news" data-transition="slide" onclick="selectLink(this);">
         <img src="img/start/btnnews.png" width="320px" height="40px" class="link" />
      </a>
  </li>
```

and my css ->

```
.selected_link {
background: repeat-y scroll 15px 6px #00FF00;
position: relative;
clear: both;
float: left;
opacity: 0.7;
```

}

this works fine -> BUT <- the img gets the opacity too... how can i solve this? i tried to give the .link the opacity 1.0 (!important) but that doesn't fix the problem. In my Browser it works fine, but not on iOS

Answer (score 1):

i got i work with JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hide_selection(){
        var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
        for(i=0; i<lnks.length; i++){
            if (lnks[i].className == "selected_link"){
                lnks[i].className = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    function selectLink(ob){
        hide_selection();
        ob.className = "selected_link";
    }
</script>
```

and then the link ->

```
<a href="#dienstleistungen" data-transition="slide" onclick="selectLink(this);">
```